# How to define a Python class with type-hints on the fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

In C++, when I define a class, the user immediately knows the type of each field:

```
class Person  {
      string name;
      int age;
}
```

I would like to do the same in Python, i.e., define a class like this:

```
class Person:
     name: str
     age: int
```

But this does not work.
Is there a way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself - the error happened in python 3.5. The code I wrote works perfectly in python 3.7.

```
#!python3.7

class Person:
    name:str
    age:int

p = Person()
print(p)
```

I keep it here in case someone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have answered your question, I am going to leave this here for future readers.

Unlike in Java, C or other such languages, Python variables are identifiers. They are simply "names" to identify the "data" stored under that specific `name`. That being said, let me prove this with an example (relative to your question)

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def _printer(self):
        print(f'Hello {self.name}, I see you are {self.age} years old!')


dave_1 = Person("Dave", 12)

dave_2 = Person(12, "Dave")

dave_1._printer()

dave_2._printer()
```

In the class Person, I have set `name` to be a String and `age` to be an integer. That is simply for code readability, so that if someone were to use my class, they would know what the class is expecting.

The output when this module is run:

```
python3 test.py
Hello Dave, I see you are 12 years old!
Hello 12, I see you are Dave years old!
```

From the output you can see, the data types provided hold no logic, but are only there to improve code readability!

Comment: While all of this is true, the readability comes from IDEs that a) make the type known while typing, and b) at least set type mismatches as warnings.

Answer (score -2):

You need to define initialization class before calling pythons.

self => Stands for your object name.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
     self.name = str()
     self.age = int()
```